# IBM Worklight 6.1 - How to integrate worklight adapter with backbone view?

Tags: backbone.js, ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using IBM Worklight 6.1 and backbone.js for my mobile app project. My question is, how to integrate Worklight adapter with backbone view?

Worklight adapter

Username.xml

```
<wl:adapter name="Username"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:wl="http://www.worklight.com/integration"
    xmlns:http="http://www.worklight.com/integration/http">

    <displayName>Username</displayName>
    <description>Username</description>
    <connectivity>
        <connectionPolicy xsi:type="http:HTTPConnectionPolicyType">
            <protocol>http</protocol>
            <domain>example.com</domain>
            <port>9081</port>           
        </connectionPolicy>
        <loadConstraints maxConcurrentConnectionsPerNode="2" />
    </connectivity>

    <procedure name="getUsername"> </procedure>
    
</wl:adapter>
```

Username-impl.js

```
function getUsername(userAlias,locale) {
    path = "rest-rib/service/Login/login_username?userAlias=" + userAlias + "&locale=" + locale;
    
    var input = {
        method : 'post',
        returnedContentType : 'json',
        path : path
    };
    
    
    return WL.Server.invokeHttp(input);
}
```

BackboneView

HomeView.js

```
define(['jquery', 'underscore', 'backbone', 'text!modules/home/homeViewTemplate.html'], function($, _, Backbone, homeViewTemplate) {
    var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
        initialize: function() {
            this.$el.off();
        },
        render: function() {
            this.$el.html(homeViewTemplate);
        },
    });
    return HomeView;
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure about an adapter, but you can take a look at this blog post and video, describing how to build MVC applications with IBM Worklight and backbone.js.

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/building_mvc_applications_with_ibm_worklight_and_backbone_js?lang=en

> The goal of this tutorial is to demonstrate how to create a MVC
>   application with IBM Worklight and backbone.js.
> Note that solid
>   knowledge of both Worklight and Backbone.js is recommended for a
>   maximum result.
>  We will create a simple application that will retrieve
>   RSS feed from Worklight adapter and display it on a screen. Clicking
>   on a feed item will popup feed description in alert box.